# how can I pass the Google API Key for google.maps.Geocoder().geocode()

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

Please provide me proper solution for following code

how can I pass the Google API Key

```
function load_map_from_address(mapid, address) {
        // check if gps has been locally cached.     
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        //alert(geocoder);
        var geocoderAPIKey = 'geocoderAPIKey ';
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            //alert(status);
            if (status == "OK") {

                var gps = results[0].geometry.location;
                create_map(gps.lat(), gps.lng(), mapid);
            }
            else {
                $('#' + mapid).html('<div class="map_canvas_text "><h4>address not found</h4></div>').show();

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mention it when you include the Google map js . Something like .

Path-to-google-map js?key=yourApiKey

In you're script tag

Comment: i wanna add in same function 

geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) 

any way to add it? @Taylor

Comment: @HardikMasalawala i dont think so . if there would have any way .. google will not suggest to add it with JS file path